# How do I print out the Phone number from a csv with padded 0 using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I have a CSV file with the following content:

```
Person,Phone
One,08001111111
Two,08002222222
Three,08003333333
```

When I used the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test_stuff.csv')
print(df)
```

It prints out:

```
  Person       Phone
0    One  8001111111
1    Two  8002222222
2  Three  8003333333
```

It removed the starting 0 from the Phone column. I then tried to add the phone as string in the csv file, like so:

```
Person,Phone
One,'08001111111'
Two,'08002222222'
Three,'08003333333'
```

However, the result is now this:

```
  Person          Phone
0    One  '08001111111'
1    Two  '08002222222'
2  Three  '08003333333'
```

What can I do to resolve this? I am hoping for a result like this:

```
  Person        Phone
0    One  08001111111
1    Two  08002222222
2  Three  08003333333
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to add the zeros back, just don't delete them in the first place by telling [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) that you column is a string:

```
pd.read_csv('test_stuff.csv', dtype={'Phone': 'str'})
```

output:

```
  Person        Phone
0    One  08001111111
1    Two  08002222222
2  Three  08003333333
```